# php long list of if ($thispage or $thispage)

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a nav that I need to display different items based on the page it is rendered, so I am using the following

`if ($thisPage=="page one" or $thisPage=="page two" or $thisPage=="page three")`

and it works fine, problem is I might need more than just three pages, and I could need to add more time to time, making it a long list, is there a way to have an array holding all the pages that I can call in the if statement, which would make it simpler to maintain (i.e. adding the new page I could need)?

Comment: Check out [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). It might do the trick.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question entirely, but wouldn't [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)  help to make your code a lot more readable?

Comment: MagnusEriksson and fvu, I guess is what Stephen R is suggesting. Issue is I wouldn't have known how, apologies if I gave impression of knowing the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities, depending on what exactly you're doing:

`if( in_array( $thisPage, array('page one', 'page two', 'page three') ) )`

You can put whatever page names in the array and pass it in, or do it directly as I have done above.

OR

```
switch ($thisPage) {
    case 'page one':
        ...
        break;
    case 'page two':
        ...
        break;
    case 'page three':
        ...
        break;
}
```

UPDATE: You can set the results of a function to a variable to avoid running the same test multiple times. For example:

`$x = in_array( $thisPage, array('page one', 'page two', 'page three') )`

This sets $x to True or False. Later you can simply use:

`if( $x ) ...`

UPDATE: You should also be aware of "pass through" on the PHP switch construct.  Each branch of the logic continues downward until it sees the "break" statement.  So if you want one command to continue, or have one command for multiple possibilities, you can leave off the "break".  For example

```
switch ($thisPage) {
    case 'page one':
    case 'page two':
    case 'page three':
        // pages one two and three will run this code
        break;
    case 'page four':
        // page four will run this code
        // note the lack of "break"
    case 'page five':
        //pages four and five will run this code
        break;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the first option :)

Comment: Yes I'd say first is better, though is shortening not as much as I would have liked, but better than what I had. FYI what I am doing is if the page is any of these (1, 2, 3, ... n) do this, if the page is this (x) do this other, if page is this (y) do yet this other stuff, and so on.

Comment: One more question if I may: would it be possible to have this condition stored (in a variable??) and be called in different cases, where the "do this" would be different?

Comment: Difficult to answer without more specifics, but it sounds like you would probably create a function for that. Do you mean the same “ifs” but different “thens”?  Maybe just take the more complicated “ifs” and set the results to a variable (true or false), then test the variable instead of the whole in_array()

Comment: "you mean the same “ifs” but different “thens”?" - Yes that's what I mean, I will try to study how to do what you suggest (setting results to variables etc.), see it bit hard, but I'll see; although as of now there are only 3 "thens", so no big deal, it was in case for future additions. BTW where do I set the "accepted answer".

Comment: There should be a check mark next to my answer. Click it and it will turn green (Accepted)

Comment: @keneso -- I added a new example that might interest you.  See the "pass through" info above

Comment: I'd guess the variable best fits my need, really appreciated.

Comment: It goes without saying, but use a more descriptive variable name than $x. Future You will thank you ;-)